# Filter products by orders type

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get all products in orders of type "assigned".
But there is something wrong on my sql, I think the `where orders.id in ()` is the problem. But I can't figured out how to do that.

Products are in many orders with different type (assigned, retired, service). I need to filter products in latest orders of type "assigned", excluding "service".

```sql
select `products`.`id` from `products` 
inner join `orders_products` on `products`.`id` = `orders_products`.`product_id` 
inner join `orders` on `orders_products`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id` 
where orders.id in (
    select MAX(order_id) from `orders_products` 
    where `product_id` = products.id
) 
and `orders`.`type_id` in (
    select `id` from `order_types` where `code` in ('assigned')
) 
group by products.id
```

#### Sample data

**order_types**

```
[
  {id: 1, code: "assigned"},
  {id: 2, code: "retired"},
  {id: 3, code: "service"},
]
```

**products**

```
[
  {id: 1},
  {id: 2},
  {id: 3},
  {id: 4},
  {id: 5}
]
```

**orders**

```
[
  {id: 1, type_id: 1}, // assigned
  {id: 2, type_id: 3}, // service
  {id: 3, type_id: 3}, // service
  {id: 4, type_id: 2}, // retired
  {id: 5, type_id: 1}, // assigned
  {id: 6, type_id: 3}, // service
  {id: 7, type_id: 3}, // service
]
```

**orders_products**

```
[
  {order_id: 1, product_id: 1}, <--
  {order_id: 2, product_id: 1},
  {order_id: 3, product_id: 2},
  {order_id: 4, product_id: 3},
  {order_id: 5, product_id: 4}, <--
  {order_id: 6, product_id: 4},
  {order_id: 7, product_id: 5},
]
```

#### Looking for results

SQL must returns products id `1, 4`

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

What you are describing sounds like:

```
select op.product_id
from orders_products op join
     orders o
     on op.order_id = o.id join
     order_types ot
     on ot.id = oo.type_id and
        ot.code = 'assigned'
group by op.product_id;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and read.
- Backticks are just make everything look messy and hard-to-write and hard-to-read.
- I see no reason for the first subquery in your `where` clause.
- You don't need the `products` table, because the product id is in `order_products`.

Comment: I edit my question, I forgot to mention about different order types and getting latest order of type "assigned", but excluding type "service". 
sorry